# How do I define a function that accepts a subscripted variable?

Tags: function-construction, argument-patterns, subscript

How do I define a function with subscripted variable? I want to write the following expression

$\qquad f[a_9] =1+ a_7 + a_9$

I wrote

```
f[Subscript[a, 9]_] := 1 + [Subscript[a, 7]+ [Subscript[a, 9]
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Side remark: ["3. Avoid using subscripted symbols in your code."](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/4999)

Answer (score 2):

Ordinarily, you don't need indicate that the argument is subscripted. If you were to define `f` with

```
f[u_] := 1 + Subscript[a, 7] + u
```

Then `f` will accept any argument including a subscripted variable. For example

```
f[42]
```

> `43 + Subscript[a, 7]`

```
Subscript[a, 9] = 42; f[Subscript[a, 9]]
```

> `43 + Subscript[a, 7]`

```
Subscript[a, 9] =.; f[Subscript[a, 9]]
```

> `1 + Subscript[a, 7] + Subscript[a, 9]`

However, if your intention is to restrict `f` to accept only subscripted forms as it argument, then you need to do something like this:

```
Clear[f]
f::badarg = "argument not a subscripted form";
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]
f[u : Subscript[_, _]] := 1 + Subscript[a, 7] + u
f[___] /; (Message[f::badarg]; False) = Null;
```

Then arguments that are not subscripted forms will be rejected; given such a form `f` will not evaluate.

[image: badarg]

The other two example given above will still work exactly as they did.

Answer (score 2):

> It is now 2023 and Mathematica version 13.2 and this problem still
> exists.

Just do

```
f[Subscript[a_, 9]] := 1 + Subscript[a, 7] + Subscript[a, 9]
f[Subscript[a, 9]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

ps. Subscript variables are bad. Avoid them. I never use them myself.

V 13.3 on windows 10